# Replicating Directory.GetFiles(String, String) in Java

Tags: c#, java

### Overview

I'm in the process of porting a simple utility app over from C# into Java and as part of this I'm writing some helper methods for items where I prefer C#'s semantics. Once such case is [`Directory.GetFiles`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3hwtke0f.aspx).

### Current Code

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FilenameFilter;

public class Directory {
    public static String[] GetFiles(String path) {        
        File directory = new File(path);
    
         return directory.list(new FilenameFilter() {
            @Override
            public boolean accept(File dir, String filename) {
                return new File(dir, filename).isFile();
            }
        });
     }
}
```

### Question

Whilst the above all seems fine, and replicates one of the GetFiles overloads, I'm stuck on how best to write a method that replicates the functionality of C#'s [`Directory.GetFiles(String, String)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wz42302f.aspx).

This method should take a `path` string, as well as a `searchPattern`, which is used to return only files matching that particular pattern.

For example, each of the following should work:

```
// Used to get all JavaScript files
Directory.GetFiles("~/Documents/", "*.js");

// Get all CSS files in the styles sub-folder.
Directory.GetFiles("~/Documents/", "styles/*.css");
```

Comment: does [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wz42302f.aspx) not working for you?

Comment: @Tigran that appears to be the same link I have in the question (the one which explains C#'s version)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could modify the pattern by placing a period before each asterisk and question mark, and then use this as a regular expression to determine which files you should return.  So, you could write something like

```
public static String[] GetFiles(final String path, final String searchPattern) {
    final Pattern re = Pattern.compile(searchPattern.replace("*", ".*").replace("?", ".?"));
    return new File(path).list(new FilenameFilter() {
        @Override
        public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
            return new File(dir, name).isFile() && re.matcher(name).matches();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: He could run into problems while searching for files that have characters such as {, [ or (. Those are valid characters for file names but that modify the regex behavior.

Comment: @Adam Thanks for this, unfortunately it doesn't work with relative paths... only files that exist in the root directory. For example "*.js" works, but "subdir/*.js" does not.

Answer (score 0):

Using Adam Michalcin's answer as a base, I've come up with the following (note these methods return an array of absolute paths:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FilenameFilter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Directory {
    public static String[] GetFiles(String path) {        
        File directory = new File(path);

        File[] matchingFiles = directory.listFiles(new FilenameFilter() {

            @Override
            public boolean accept(File dir, String filename) {
                return new File(dir, filename).isFile();
            }
        });

        ArrayList<String> files = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (File file : matchingFiles) {
            files.add(file.getAbsolutePath());
        }

        return (String[])files.toArray(new String[files.size()]);
    }

    public static String[] GetFiles(String path, final String searchPattern) {
        // Split the searchPattern incase we have directories in there
        ArrayList<String> pattern = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(searchPattern.split("/")));

        // Take the last element out from the array, as this will be the file pattern
        String filePattern = pattern.remove(pattern.size() - 1);

        // Insert the base path into the remaining list
        pattern.add(0, path);

        // Now lets concat the lot to create a base path
        path = Path.combine((String[])pattern.toArray(new String[pattern.size()]));

        final Pattern regEx = Pattern.compile(filePattern.replace("*", ".*").replace("?", ".?"));
        File directory = new File(path);

        File[] matchingFiles = directory.listFiles(new FilenameFilter() {

            @Override
            public boolean accept(File dir, String filename) {
                return new File(dir, filename).isFile() && regEx.matcher(filename).matches();
            }
        });

        ArrayList<String> files = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (File file : matchingFiles) {
            files.add(file.getAbsolutePath());
        }

        return (String[])files.toArray(new String[files.size()]);
    }
}
```

This also utilizes another helper I've put in place (`Path.combine`):

```
import java.io.File;

public class Path {
    public static String combine(String... paths)
    {
        File file = new File(paths[0]);

        for (int i = 1; i < paths.length ; i++) {
            file = new File(file, paths[i]);
        }

        return file.getPath();
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```
Directory.GetFiles("/Users/beardtwizzle/", "/Documents/javascripts/*.js");
```

This does still the other character problem that Bruno Silva mentions. So will try and bake a fix in for that too.